# Is it possible to handle fractions of multivariate rational polynomials using flint or bpas lib

Tags: flint

I have to simplify such expressions: `(1 + 2*a)/(b*(1 + c)) - 1/c`, simplifying this expression i need to get something like this: `(2*a*c - b*c - b + c) / (b*c*(c + 1))`. I tried to use **fmpz_mpoly_q** from flint/calcium library and **SparseMultivariateRationalPolynomial** from Bpas library but I've encountered a problem: it seems not possible to quickly convert `(1 + 2*a)/(b*(1 + c)) - 1/c` to class entity  and then get simplified expression because both of classes expects to get denominator and numerator of this expression.

Is there really no way out of this problem, except to write a some kind of parser that will return denominator and numerator?